# Why is AspNet Core IDataProtection Azure Storage Using Inner Key

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, azure-blob-storage

I've been at this for a couple of days and can't see what I'm doing wrong. I would appreciate it if someone can show me what I'm doing wrong.

I've gone through multiple iterations. This is what I currently have that is not working.

Startup.cs

```
var creds = new StorageCredentials(settings.CloudStorageAccount, settings.CloudStorageKey);
var account = new CloudStorageAccount(creds, true);
var blobClient = account.CreateCloudBlobClient();
var container = blobClient.GetContainerReference($"{dpsFolder}-{_env.EnvironmentName}".ToLower());
container.CreateIfNotExistsAsync().GetAwaiter().GetResult();
services.AddDataProtection()
        .SetApplicationName(settings.ApplicationName)
        .PersistKeysToAzureBlobStorage(container, dpsFileName);
```

Controller ctor

```
public ExternalSettingController([FromServices] IExternalSettingRepo repo,
                                [FromServices] IOptions<AppSettings> opts,
                                [FromServices] ILogger<ExternalSettingController> logger,
                                [FromServices] IHostingEnvironment env,
                                [FromServices] IDataProtectionProvider dpp)
        : base(opts, repo, logger)
    {
        _dataProtector = dpp.CreateProtector("blah.Integration");

    }
```

Actual call in a Get method

```
toReturn.Plain = _dataProtector.Unprotect(found.SettingValue);
```

Everything seems to load OK, as best as I can tell through the debugger. The settings are correct. When the call to Unprotect is made the system is choosing to use one of the keys from C:\Users\blah\AppData\Local\ASP.NET\DataProtection-Keys instead of the one uploaded to Azure Blob Storage.

A little background since it could be affecting things. I had originally created a separate DataProtectionService class that did the encrypting with IDataProtection using a key I maintained for the project. That does not install in a readable place on Azure so I had to switch where it is stored. That is the key in Azure Storage now. The data I'm trying to decrypt was originally encrypted when the same key was stored locally.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just changed the title to this, now that I understand what happened. One part of it is that I had two Guids that started with the same sequence and that confused me. One was on my computer. The other was added to the keys file that had been uploaded to Azure Blob Storage.

That does not explain the problem though. Here is the explanation in hopes it helps someone else over time:

Once things got switched to run under Azure Blob Storage the Data Protection sub system added a second key to the keys.xml file on Azure. That key went inside the initial `<key>` element already in existence. It created a nested `<key>` element inside the root `<key>` element. For an unknown reason, possibly a bug, the key ring code in Data Protection then ignored the root `<key>` element, which represents the key I needed and only loaded the nested `<key>` element.

To solve this I switched them. The newly generated one is now the root key and the older one is the nested key. With that the proper key got loaded and all is happy now.